# Get Wordpress Image URL not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I am using the following to get data on Wordpress Woocommerce products. I output the product data in json.

```
 <?php
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 200, 'product_cat' => 'clothes');
       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );


    $send_array = array();
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        global $product; 

    $send_array[] = array(

        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'content' => get_the_content(),
        'regular_price' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true),
        'image' =>wp_get_attachment_image_src(),
        'sale_price'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true)
    );

     endwhile; 

     wp_reset_query(); 
        ob_clean();
        echo json_encode($send_array);
        exit();

    ?>
```

This code works fine and outputs the data correctly. However the `image` doesn't seem to work.

I want to get the image url for each product. In the code above I tried `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`, but no luck.

How do I use the code above to get the image url for each product and place it as the value to the `image` key in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your not calling corectly the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` function. 
It requires the ID of the desired attachment, which you can get using `get_post_thumbnail_id()` function.

But the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returns an array containing the image attributes `"url"`, `"width"` and `"height"` of an attachment file.

I suggest to use the `wp_get_attachment url()` function, which returns a only the URL.

Finnaly, this code should work fine for you:

```
 $send_array[] = array(

    'id' => get_the_ID(),
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'content' => get_the_content(),
    'regular_price' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true),
    'image' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) ),
    'sale_price'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true)
);
```

More info about this functions on wordpress codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: Worked like a charm. Also the links were very helpful. Thanks very much.